# Flutter Dependency error

Tags: flutter

how to add Sqflite dependency in flutter?

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.0
  sqflite: any
  english_words: "^3.1.0"
```

Comment: What is the error message? What is the output of `flutter doctor`?

Comment: Try `sqflite: ^0.8.9`

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct way of doing it. Try running `packages get` (again).

You can specify versions with either the exact version `sqflite: ^0.8.9`, a range `sqflite: >=0.8.0 <0.9.9` or just `sqflite: any`, which will always get you the latest version.

There is an in-depth [guide on this topic](https://flutter.io/using-packages/) available.

Comment: always give me error missing semi colon I think there may be spacing issue ..please  verify..and sorry for my bad English ..I hope you got my point..

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
sqflite: ^0.11.0(Latest version till date)
```

To the pubspec.yaml file.
Tap on packages get and your dependency will be added.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the latest version of sqflite just leave it blank, like so:

```
  sqflite:
```

This will always find the latest version of sqflite. Make sure you run:

```
flutter packages get
```

from your terminal.

Sometimes my dependencies take a while to add to the project. If you can't import the package in your code, try closing down your editor. When you open it back up it should add the new dependencies with no issues.